# What is the stable rubygems version for rails 2.3.11?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Right now i have rubygems version 1.3.7. I have just installed rails 2.3.11 and i want update my rubygems also. What is the stable rubygems version for rails 2.3.11.

Answer (score 6):

I'm running 2.3.11 with RubyGems 1.7.2 without having to require 'thread' or make any other modifications to existing Rails code. The 1.8 series causes problems for me so I downgraded.

```
gem uninstall rubygems-update #and choose all versions if asked
gem install rubygems-update -v 1.7.2
update_rubygems
gem -v
  => 1.7.2
```

Comment: And if you're using rvm, you can `rvm rubygems 1.7.2`. Although it appears that rvm can only have one rubygems loaded per ruby, so that rubygems will apply to all of your gemsets on that ruby.

Comment: More info here: http://blog.majesticseacreature.com/summary-of-rubygems-18-breakage-reports

Answer (score 2):

This worked perfectly for me to downgrade from RubyGems 1.8.10 (for Rails 3) to 1.37 (for Rails 2):

`gem update --system 1.3.7`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 1.5.2 with 2.x ror apps fine.

You should be able to upgrade to 1.5.3 without changing your 2.x apps

1.6.1 has just been released : [rubygems-1.6.1](http://blog.segment7.net/2011/03/03/rubygems-1-6-1) - Rubygems 1.6 has a deprecation warning for rails 2.x and in the [changelog](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/History.txt#L16)

***RubyGems no longer requires ‘thread’. Rails < 3 will need to add require ‘thread’ to their applications.***

Don't think it's a big deal but you probably will have to add that small requirement to all your 2.x apps if you install 1.6